# How can an ObservableCollection fire a Replace action?

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

In the documentation of the event args of NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs, there is an [action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx) called Replace (in addition to Add, Remove, Move, etc.). When can this be fired? I can't see any Replace method in ObservableCollection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>;
myCollection.Add("One");
myCollection.Add("Two");
myCollection.Add("Three");
myCollection.Add("Four");
myCollection.Add("Five");

myCollection[4] = "Six"; // Replace (i.e. Set)
```